# laravel register does not update users table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication, homestead

I am pretty new to laravel and having some difficulty with the authorization process. I have recreated an empty users table in mysql using **php artisan migrate:refresh**. When I go to the registration page fill out the fields and hit register, my table in mysql does not get updated. I am redirected to the correct weblink I set, so that part seems to be working.

I have made sure that mysql is connected to my laravel project, so the connection isn't the problem.

Below is the code in the AuthController.php. The views for register and login were made with the **php artisan make:auth** command.

```
   protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    }
```

Below is the code in my User.php file which is in the app directory.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class Users extends Authenticatable
   {
    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

Comment: Instead of `return User::create()` do `$user = User::create()` and then afterwards, do a `dd($user);` what is the result?

Comment: The result is the same, it take me to the web link I sent but I still have nothing in my mysql table. I tried   $user =  User::create([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
    do($user)

Comment: and this   $user =  User::create([

            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                do($user)
        ]);
    }

Comment: not `do` but `dd`. `dd` stands for `dump and die` and is a provided function from laravels helpers.

Comment: I changed it to dd there was no difference from before

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `create` you need to specify in `User model` `$fillable array`

```
protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'password',
        'name',
    ];
```

OR $protected (so value want update)
Read more [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: I have that in my User.php file, which is in the app directory. Do I need to add it somewhere else ?

Comment: Actually you can just call `->unguard()` on the instance of the model prior to `->fill()` and bypass the fillable restriction.

Comment: @ray Nope if you have them